# Windows 10 starts freezing after some time

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze

After the fresh install, Windows 10 is starting out OK. However, after few days of use it starts freezing randomly, taking too long to respond to mouse clicks or key presses. Task Manager shows 100% of disk usage. When I reboot it, it goes into "start up repair", but fails to repair it.

I reinstall it, and the same happens again, it works fine for a few days and then freezes.

I use HP Pavilion P17, windows 10 home from Microsoft official website, installed via USB tool.

Comment: I _guess_ that your harddrive is failing - could you provide some SMART-values?
Tools: [GSmartControl](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/home/index.php/Downloads) or [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/download/index-e.html), with GSmartControl being able to start self-tests on the hard drive and CrystalDiskInfo being the tool with the nicer (and more helpful) GUI. (Both are freeware.)
The most interesting values (imho) would be the **drive model**, **raw read error rate**, and **reallocated sector count**.

Comment: Which process takes that much disk usage shown in task manager?

Comment: I had a similar issue with my old-ish Acer Aspire 5750G laptop and Windows 10.  Initially it ran fine, but started freezing randomly after Jan 2016 big update release.  Eventually reverted to Windows 7 and the issue went away.  I use Linux Mint as my primary OS (dual boot on the same HDD, no issues).  This causes me to blame Windows 10, instead of blaming my hardware...

Comment: @flolilolilo is there a way to repair failing hard-drive? (google did not reveal anything worthwhile)

Comment: If you are sure (or want to eliminate the possibility) that your HDD is failing, then you can't really do anything to change that. buy a new drive as soon as possible and see if the problem still occurs. However, we still don't have enough information (processes with high disk usage in task manager, SMART values) to help you.